Why does ASH (shell) not find my commands executed through "sudo"?
To use a command with the "echo into a file" redirection operator >> through sudo... command, I
have written that to redirect through standard input to the sudo process, executed as the superuser.
The command to redirect was echo "tun" >> /etc/modules-load.d/tun.conf, here I put whoami in its place.
I tried
echo 'whoami' | sudo -i '$SHELL -c "exec $(< /dev/stdin)"'

and next,
echo 'whoami' | sudo -i '$SHELL -c "$(< /dev/stdin)"'

and sh responded -sh: /bin/sh -c "$(< /dev/stdin)": not found.
What is that for? Why does the Alpine Linux distribution shell not find my commands executed through sudo?
sudo -V (version number and compiled versions):
Sudo version 1.9.15p5
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.9.15p5
Sudoers file grammar version 50
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.9.15p5
Sudoers audit plugin version 1.9.15p5

Thank you for anything answered! 

echo 'whoami' | sudo -i $SHELL -c "exec $(< /dev/stdin)"

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think you need exec $(< /dev/stdin) in two ', sorry.

why? Have you run it?

Note that the error message says that the file /bin/sh -c "$(< /dev/stdin)" is not found.  It tries to execute that whole string as a command because you told sudo to do so (the string was the only argument to the command, apart from the unnecessary -i option).
Instead, you'd want to use
echo whoami | sudo "$SHELL" -c 'exec $(< /dev/stdin)'

... which runs $SHELL with -c and exec $(< /dev/stdin) as arguments.  Note, though, that if $SHELL is a shell that does not understand process substitutions, such as sh, you would not expect the in-line shell script to produce any output.  Instead, use $SHELL -s (run the shell and get it to read its commands from standard input):
$ echo whoami | sudo "$SHELL" -s
root


Thank you! Why can't the whole string with "exec $" be executed?

@EdwardJ Because there is no such command.  It's the difference between ls -l and "ls -l" (try it). One is a command with an option, the other a command that does not exist.

OK, the answer works.
